# communicate between angular webapp and chrome extension

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send localstorage data of webapp to the chrome extension
I followed this link https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage
added this part in component.ts file

```
var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

and this part in background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url === blocklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```

But It ended up giving me error **Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.**
I have tried some potential solutions but it is not working

Comment: There are several possibilities. 1) editorExtensionId is incorrect, 2) either externally_connectable or background.js are incorrectly declared in manifest.json, 3) onMessageExternal part you've shown is inside asynchronously running code, 4) you didn't reload the extension after editing, 5) a bug in Chrome. BTW you can read `localStorage` of the web app in your extension's content script directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response @wOxxOm.  first 4 possibilities are not causing the issue. Not sure about 5th. I will try to read localStorage from content script

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm working on a Chrome extension that needs to react to login/logout changes in a web app. 
My plan is to:
Inject the content script to access the web app's localStorage.
Detect login/logout changes.
Use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to communicate these changes to the extension.
But every time I need to refresh the webpage to detect changes in the extension. How can I detect the login/logout changes without refreshing the webpage

Comment: Show the code that detects the changes.

Comment: I want to know that only how can I detect the changes

**const key = "some-key";
const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "storeValue", key: key, value: value });**
and in background script I want to perform some actions. But need to refresh the webpage every time to reflect changes in extension @wOxxOm

Comment: Specify `"world":"MAIN"` for the content script and override `localStorage.setItem = (k, v) => { Storage.prototype.setItem.call(localStorage, k,v); chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, ......) }`. Note that the site may be using `localStorage[key]=val` in which case you'll have to override window.localStorage = new Proxy(localStorage, {set: (obj, k, v) => ....... })

Comment: @wOxxOm How can I observe realtime changes in localstorage of webapp  in the chrome extension. When I inject the content script in webapp, It gives me localstorage data but if there is any changes in the localstorage, I need to refresh the webapp to get updated value of localstorage in the chrome extension. how can fetch realtime changes without refreshing webpage

Comment: See my last comment, it explains how.